# XQUERY: Finding number of occurences from one query in another

Tags: xpath, xquery

I know there should be a simple solution to this but I can't seem to figure it out. Suppose I have a query which returns something like:

```
xs:untypedAtomic("A"),
xs:untypedAtomic("B"),
xs:untypedAtomic("C")
```

and I have another one which returns something like:

```
xs:untypedAtomic("B"),
xs:untypedAtomic("B"),
xs:untypedAtomic("B"),
xs:untypedAtomic("A"),
xs:untypedAtomic("C"),
xs:untypedAtomic("A")
```

How do I get the number of occurences for each letter in the second table?

Answer (score 2):

I propose two variants, one containing a group by clause, that happens to show the wanted characteristics for the non-grouping variable $cntr (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by for details on how grouping is performed):

```
let $seq := ("B", "B","B","A","C","A")
let $cntr := 1
for $it in $seq
group by $it
return <el>{
  attribute num {count($cntr)},
  $it  
}</el>
```

My second, maybe more obvious, variant would be:

```
let $seq := ("B", "B","B","A","C","A")
for $v in distinct-values($seq)
    return <el>{
      attribute num {count($seq[. = $v])},
      $v
    }</el>
```

As my answer has been a little imprecise, here comes a minor correction inspired by  Dimitre Novatchev answer.

Instead of using:

```
for $v in distinct-values($seq)
```

you may as well use

```
for $v in ("A", "B", "C") (: this is sequence 1 as stated in the question:)
```

which more closely resembles the questions two sequences, given that this very sequence contains distinct values only.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
for $s in $vMySeq
       return
          ($s, count(index-of($vSeq, $s)))
```

where `$vMySeq` is the result of the first query and `$vSeq` is the result of the second query.

**A complete example**:

```
   let $vMySeq := ('A', 'B', 'C'),
       $vSeq := ('B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A')
     return
         for $s in $vMySeq
           return
                  ($s, count(index-of($vSeq, $s)))
```

**The result is**:

```
A 2 B 3 C 1
```